# "Error building Docker image for .NET Framework 4.7.2 on Windows Server Core: 'failed to register layer: no such file or directory'"

Tags: asp.net, .net, dockerfile, docker-container

I've created a Dockerfile for my application, but despite trying various runtime versions and configurations, I'm still encountering issues with its functionality. Regardless of the runtime versions and types.

Could anyone provide guidance or insights into resolving this issue? I've tried multiple runtime versions and configurations, but none seem to work.

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to register layer: link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory
```

My web application is built using .NET Framework 4.7.2. Despite trying to specify this exact version as the runtime within my Dockerfile, I'm encountering the same persistent error during the build process.

I've attempted various combinations with different base images such as 4.7 and 4.7.2, along with windowsservercore-2016, 2019, and 2022. However, the issue persists.

As per the Docker Hub documentation, it's mentioned that even if the specified runtime is 4.8 or 4.8.1, it should still accommodate the 4.7.2 version, which aligns with what I'm using. Despite this, the error continues.

My Docker version is 24.0.7, build afdd53b. I'm seeking guidance on how to successfully build the image and subsequently run the website as a containerized service.

I have attached the dockerfile for the reference.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Dockerfile:

```
# .NET Framework runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Setting working directory within the container
WORKDIR /webapp/

# Copying published application to the container
COPY . .

# Port of the application
EXPOSE 80

# Command to start the application
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code and errors as text and not as images (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) ).

Comment: what platform are you building on? https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/370

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Docker Desktop on Windows and currently the active builder is 'desktop-linux'. It means your container has no access to Windows specific libraries or features (hence the error about missing DLL file)

In your system tray right click on the Docker Desktop icon and select "Switch to Windows containers..."